# Can some one ping tails/tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, tails

I know that my traffic is encrypted and Tor scrubs my information on its way to the first node. Only a bad node may get my IP. How about when my data is in transit. Is the IP hidden? Can some one Ping me and hack me if they know my IP address while I am using Tails/Tor (assuming all data goes through Tor)?

Comment: Tor only supports TCP. Ping uses ICMP.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that my traffic is encrypted
>   and Tor scrubs my information on its way to the first node.

Tor does not change/censor the data you transfer, it just encrypts it with the public keys of the relays in the circuit.

> Only a bad node may get my IP.

Good or bad, the 1st node (Guard) always knows your IP address, and no other node knows your IP address. (Except the exit if you transfer it as part of the data, unencrypted.)

> How about when my data is in transit. Is the IP hidden?

Your data is always 'in transit'.

Your Tor client has a TCP connection to your Guard. The Guard knows your IP and your ISP knows you connect to your Guard to use Tor. (Obviously, your ISP knows your IP, because they gave it to you.) The 2nd node does not know your IP.

> Can some one Ping me and hack me if they know my IP address while I am using tails/tor(assuming all data goes through tor)?

When someone knows your IP address, they can ping you. This is not through Tor. (It is up to your router to reply to  ping.)
Whether someone can hack you depends on whether your network and computer have vulnerabilities that are exposed to the internet. Regardless of Tor.
When someone uses your IP address for an attack, then they do not go through Tor. An attack through Tor would most likely be an attack on your browser and not use/need your IP address.